# Openedge - Read XML from URL

Tags: xml, progress-4gl, openedge

I need to read XML file from an URL. I have no problems if the file is physically present. Then i parse it using the SAX reader.

Now i need to read a XML file from an URL - twice.

First time in need to get it from `http://someurl/paging$1,1` , then extract value from `total-items` in the head of the document.

After that I need to get the XML from the same url , only with last `1` replaced with value from `total-items` . This way i get all the items that are available for me.

Now I'm stumped already at the beginning. How do I make progress to read XML from URL ? I see there is an option with READ-XML(), but that one stores it in temp-tables.

Using Progress Openedge ver. 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For "raw" xml support you can use the X-DOCUMENT handle.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE hXDoc AS HANDLE      NO-UNDO.
CREATE X-DOCUMENT hXDoc.
hXDoc:LOAD("file","http://someurl/paging$1,1", TRUE).
/* Here you need to parse */
DELETE OBJECT hXDoc.
```

Depending on the structure of the xml-document you can use READ-XML with a temp-table or a dataset to load data directly into it. But then you would need to define the dataset before. This genereally don't work well with dynamically created items.

Check out the documentation around xml [here](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge113/pdfs/dvxml/dvxml.pdf?_ga=1.35639394.237806638.1386954836)

If all things fails you could wrap a os utility like curl or wget (as regards to Tims answer). A simple wrapper around wget could look like this (curl would be similar):

```
DEFINE INPUT  PARAMETER pcUrl     AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE INPUT  PARAMETER pcPrefix  AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE OUTPUT PARAMETER pcFile    AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.

pcFile = "wget." + pcPrefix + "." + STRING(TODAY,"999999") + REPLACE(STRING(TIME,"HH:MM:SS"),":","") + "-" + STRING(RANDOM(0,1000),"9999"). 

OS-COMMAND SILENT VALUE("wget '" + pcUrl + "' -o /dev/null -O /tmp/" + pcFile).
```

Comment: This works very well, but only if i have the name of the remote xml. In this case I don't and hxDoc:LOAD fails.

Comment: That has to do with parsing of the xml, right? I don't exactly think I understand what youre trying to do. Perhaps you could clarify a bit? Including example is always helpful!

Comment: No, it fails at getting the xml from the source on `hXDoc:LOAD("file","http://myurl/paging$1,1", TRUE)`. IF I paste this URL into web browser, I get the output XML on the screen.  Now , if i try your example with my other source , which has an xml name -  `hXDoc:LOAD("file","http://myotherurl/products.xml", TRUE)` then it works. I save the x-doc with `hXDoc:SAVE(...)` and let the existing SAX parser take over. I think the problem is that I'm not accessing an actual a file on that remote system , but rather calling a web service that feeds the generated xml back... if that makes any sense.

Comment: Perhaps the http-headers isn't properly telling Progress that this really is xml? Perhaps fall back to Tim's idea - write a wrapper around curl and then load the xml from the downloaded file.

Comment: Fiddling with curl now. But your example solved the other 9/10 of my remote xml woes. It was not in vain. Thanks.

Comment: Nice. I've written a curl (or perhaps wget) wrapper in ABL. Can post it from work tomorrow.

Comment: If you're calling a webservice, then use the ABL webservice functionality directly.

Comment: @Tim Kuehn - i was only assuming that it's a kind of web service , but  bprowsdldoc doesn't see anything. More likely it's something written in ASP - at least returned header says so `X-Powered-By: ASP.NET`. I think this line in header is the source of problem  `Content-Encoding: gzip` . Trying with curl now.

Comment: @TimKuehn If the web service is REST based (most seems to be so nowadays) the built in SOAP client (using RUN or function call) won't work (I think this a major flaw in ABL). You can get around it by loading data with LOAD or READ-XML, that will unfortunently not give you things like asynchronous calls or a good way of handle errors.

Answer (score 2):

READ-XML requires the XML data to be in a storage area such as a LONGCHAR, MEMPTR, FILE, or handle.

In order to use this function with your application, you'll need to d/l the xml payload to one of those storage areas, and then read it in.

One possibility would be to create a SOCKET, use the socket to do a "get" call for the http request, read the response to a MEMPTR, then READ-XML the data into your TT.

Another option would be to use "curl" (http://curl.haxx.se/) to get the XML data to a READ-XML storage area, and then parse the XML file that way.

Comment: curl with --compressed flag delivers without a glitch (to a file). Together with wrapper pointers/code from @Jensd my problems are solved. Tough one which answer to mark, tho.